# how can I create Pivot temp table for month and year like calender

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I want to create a temp table maybe using pivot for month and year as column.

[image]

Comment: What's preventing you from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

[I mentioned the question and solution for the pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IqMi.png)

Comment: ---Creating tables
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]([PID] [int] NULL,[ProductDesc] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[ProductCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]([Date] [varchar](50) NULL,[PID] [int] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0):

Summarising the months data using pivot

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]([PID] [int] NULL,[ProductDesc] [nvarchar](50) NULL,[ProductCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]([Date] [varchar](50) NULL,[PID] [int] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

    ---insert script---
    INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode]) VALUES (1, N'Packet-Eye', N'P001')
    INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode]) VALUES (2, N'Wiggy', N'W099 ')
    INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode]) VALUES (3, N'Wimax-Lite', N'W001')
    INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([PID], [ProductDesc], [ProductCode]) VALUES (4, N'Wimax-Home', N'e W002 ')
    INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Date], [PID]) VALUES (N'1/14/2009 ', 1)
    INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Date], [PID]) VALUES (N'1/15/2009 ', 1)
    INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Date], [PID]) VALUES (N'2/1/2009', 2)
    INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Date], [PID]) VALUES (N'3/3/2009', 3)
    GO
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
      SELECT t1.productdesc as pd,COUNT(month(t2.date))as dates,
      DateName( month ,  DateAdd( month , MONTH(t2.date) , 0 ) - 1 ) as mon
      FROM table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.pid=t2.pid
      where year(date) between 2009
        and 2010 group by productdesc,month(t2.date),month (t2.date)
    ) AS D
    PIVOT
    (
    sum(dates)
       FOR mon IN( [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
    ) AS P
```